# Android NDK __android_log_print function and LogCat

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a function like

```
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "HelloNDK!");
```

on my C code

I wouldn't find that output on my LogCat. What kind of filter I need to setup

by Log Tag, by Log Message,  by Application Name, by Log Level...etc.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You don't find output because you have misused the function.  The function has the prototype:

```
int __android_log_print(int prio, const char *tag,  const char *fmt, ...);
```

So you must supply a "tag" as well as the format.

For example

```
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "MyTag", "The value is %d", some_variable);
```

Once you use the function properly, you can use any filtering method (or none at all - such as you'd get from the `adb logcat` command without further arguments) just as with java code.

Comment: Is the log printed in some file? Can we customise to print to a specific file?