# How do I Print to Console using dart:ffi in Flutter?

Tags: android, c++, flutter, dart, dart-ffi

Trying to print to console when running my Flutter app (on Android) from the following C++ code I am running through [`dart:ffi`](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

std::cout << "Hello, World!";
```

Does not give me any output in the terminal. How would I print to the Flutter terminal from C++?

---

I know my functions otherwise work correctly because I am getting correct actions on pointers / return values.

Comment: Are you able to use `__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE,...`? Would need a conditional include as obviously Android only.

Comment: @RichardHeap Thank you for pointing it out. I tried `#ifdef __ANDROID_API__
#include <android/log.h>
#endif` and used it according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/16721055/6509751. It seems I would need to include it as https://stackoverflow.com/a/27297135/6509751 says. However, that would only show up in Logcat and I want to read the output in the Flutter console.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Edit: When only running on android, there is a simpler way. I have updated the answer below.

You'll have to pass a wrapper to the print function into the native code

```dart
void wrappedPrint(Pointer<Utf8> arg){
  print(Utf8.fromUtf8(arg));
}

typedef _wrappedPrint_C = Void Function(Pointer<Utf8> a);
final wrappedPrintPointer = Pointer.fromFunction<_wrappedPrint_C>(_wrappedPrint_C);

final void Function(Pointer) initialize =
  _nativeLibrary
    .lookup<NativeFunction<Void Function(Pointer)>>("initialize")
    .asFunction<void Function(Pointer)>();

initialize(wrappedPrintPointer);
```

and then use that in your C library:

```
void (*print)(char *);

void initialize(void (*printCallback)(char *)) {
    print = printCallback;
    print("C library initialized");
}

void someOtherFunction() {
    print("Hello World");
}
```

---

When only running on android, things get simpler. Instead of all of the above, do:

Simply use the android logging mechanism, it will show up on the console, at least when using `flutter run`. I'm assuming flutter attaches to logcat using the app's PID.

To do so, update the CMakeLists.txt with:

```
find_library( # Defines the name of the path variable that stores the
              # location of the NDK library.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # CMake needs to locate.
              log )

# Links your native library against one or more other native libraries.
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       <your-libs-name-here>

                       # Links the log library to the target library.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

and in your c lib do:

```
#include <android/log.h>

void someOtherFunction() {
      __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "flutter", "Hello world! You can use %s", "formatting");
}
```

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you.

Comment: It seems that as of May 2021 (ffi v 1.0.0) the first solution doesn't seem to work, I get the error
`dart:ffi only supports calling static Dart functions from native code.`