# Printing logs via __android_log_print during using executable file

Tags: android, c++, logging, executable

I got executable compiled for Android. Inside this exec I got logs printed by `__android_log_print` but I don't see them although I should.
On the other hand I can see things printed to stdout with `std::cout`.

Anyone knows why `__android_log_print` doesn't work? And what should I do to make it work ?

Comment: Because `__android_log_print` does not write to the console.  It writes to the logger see https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/logging  _"...Writes a formatted string to the log, with priority prio and tag tag...."_

Comment: And also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720854/android-ndk-android-log-print-function-and-logcat

Comment: Do you think there is a way to attach this `__android_log_print` used in my executable to logger ?

I would like to invoke this executable from my android app. You think it's possible to attach this executable's output with logger in real-time ?